# Creating a logging function from Logary/Noop.fs in F#

Tags: f#

I am editing the Noop.fs file from [logary/Noop.fs](https://github.com/logary/logary/blob/master/src/Logary/Targets/Noop.fs).

I am currently trying to add two functions. That is the one to **create the Event Sourcing connection** (I understand I should ideally move it somewhere else, so that it is not created every time I want to log something, but it should rather exist on a global level, where should I add it then?).

The second function is to **send the log as an event to the EventStore stream**. I have created the function, but I need to call it. Where do I call it? I have tried placing it below the function, but it does not work.

Another error is on this line

```
ack *<= () (* LHS: the ACK is a unit sent to `ack` *) >>= fun () ->
```

Error: FS0010   Unexpected identifier in expression. Expected incomplete structured construct at or before this point or other token.

This is my code:

```
 | Log (message, ack) ->

         let CreateEventSourcingConnection() =
             task {
                 let connection =
                     let ipEndPoint = IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Loopback, 1113)
                     EventStoreConnection.Create(ipEndlPoint)
                 do! connection.ConnectAsync()
                 return connection
             }

         let AddEventToStreamAsync (connection: IEventStoreConnection) streamName eventName message =
             task {
                 let serializedEventData =
                     message
                     |> JsonConvert.SerializeObject
                     |> Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes
                 let event = EventData(Guid.NewGuid(), eventName, true, serializedEventData, null)

                 let! _ = connection.AppendToStreamAsync(streamName, int64 ExpectedVersion.Any, event)
                 ()
             }
         ()

         //Do something with the `message` value specific to the target
         //you are creating.

         //Don't put `use` statements in here; you need to dispose them before
         //recursing below.

         //This is a simple acknowledgement using unit as the signal
        ack *<= () (* LHS: the ACK is a unit sent to `ack` *) >>= fun () ->
                    (* RHS (above): the callback after the ACK is done *)
        loop { state = not state.state } // recurse
```