# Error: FS0010 Unexpected identifier in expression. Expected incomplete structured construct at or before this point or other token

Tags: f#

```
| Log (message, ack) ->

     let CreateEventSourcingConnection() =
         task {
             let connection =
                 let ipEndPoint = IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Loopback, 1113)
                 EventStoreConnection.Create(ipEndlPoint)
             do! connection.ConnectAsync()
             return connection
         }

     let AddEventToStreamAsync (connection: IEventStoreConnection) streamName eventName message =
         task {
             let serializedEventData =
                 message
                 |> JsonConvert.SerializeObject
                 |> Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes
             let event = EventData(Guid.NewGuid(), eventName, true, serializedEventData, null)

             let! _ = connection.AppendToStreamAsync(streamName, int64 ExpectedVersion.Any, event)
             ()
         }
     ()

     //Do something with the `message` value specific to the target
     //you are creating.

     //Don't put `use` statements in here; you need to dispose them before
     //recursing below.

     //This is a simple acknowledgement using unit as the signal
    ack *<= () (* LHS: the ACK is a unit sent to `ack` *) >>= fun () ->
                (* RHS (above): the callback after the ACK is done *)
    loop { state = not state.state } // recurse
```

Error is on this line

```
ack *<= () (* LHS: the ACK is a unit sent to `ack` *) >>= fun () ->
```

Error: FS0010 Unexpected identifier in expression. Expected incomplete structured construct at or before this point or other token.

Comment: Is the last line `loop` supposed to have the same indent level as the previous one?

Comment: No, here is the indentation from the original https://github.com/logary/logary/blob/master/src/Logary/Targets/Noop.fs. This problem appears only after I add my functions. I also cannot call these functions here.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Creating a logging function from Logary/Noop.fs in F#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59135700/creating-a-logging-function-from-logary-noop-fs-in-f)

Comment: No, unfortunately :(

Comment: What is the `()` for, just above the comments?  It looks like that's the return value from the original pattern match case, so there shouldn't be anything after it.

Comment: If I do not put () it will give me an error with the first let.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried taking the code from [Noop.fs in Logary](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/logary/logary/master/src/Logary/Targets/Noop.fs) and pasting your changes in place of the pattern matching case that matches the `Log` case.

I got the same error that you report because of indentation issue in your code. In particular, the line with `ack *<= ()` has one space less than the lines with `let` that define your two helper functions. Adding an extra space before `ack` and the following line fixes the problem.

If you remove a couple of lines from your code, you can see this clearly:

```
  let CreateEventSourcingConnection() =
      task {
          return connection
      }

  let AddEventToStreamAsync (connection: IEventStoreConnection) streamName eventName message =
      task {
          ()
      }
  ()
  //This is a simple acknowledgement using unit as the signal
 ack *<= () (* LHS: the ACK is a unit sent to `ack` *) >>= fun () ->
            (* RHS (above): the callback after the ACK is done *)
 loop { state = not state.state } // recurse
```

Comment: Diky moc. :) Id appreciate it if you could look at my other F# questions as well.